# Manage a Chinese .txt in C++

Tags: c++, utf-8

i'm trying to show in the console a cinese text, it has been pasted from wikipedia in a .txt file (i don't know the codification, maybe UTF-8?)

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
using namespace std;


    int main () {

        const locale utf8_locale
            = locale(locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>());
        std::wifstream file("dao.txt");
        file.imbue(utf8_locale);

        wstring s;

            if (file.is_open())
            {
              while (getline(file, s))
              {
                    cout << s << '\n';
                    // Do something with the string
              }
               else cout << "Unable to open file";
           myfile.close();
            }
    return 0;
    }
```

I receive: 
**error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and 'std::__cxx11::wstring {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}')|**

Why does *<<* is not overloaded?

Comment: What about using [std::wcout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout)?

Comment: You *must* know the encoding in order to be able to display it correctly.

Comment: What encoding does your terminal expect? `UTF-8`? If so just read it in as a normal `std::string` (no facets needed) and print it back out again. `UTF-16`? Then you could try printing to (and reading from) `std::wcout`? The bottom line is you have to output the same encoding that your display terminal is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors:

Else does not match if

```
        if (file.is_open())
        {
           ...
           else cout << "Unable to open file";
           ...
        }
```

Use std::wcout. `s` is a wide string. Use the wide output.

```
std::wcout << s << '\n';  // not std::cout notice the w
```

No variable called `myfile` I probably meant `file`

```
 /*my*/file.close();
```

Note:

You have to imbue the stream before opening it.

```
    std::wifstream file;
    file.imbue(utf8_locale);
    file.open("dao.txt");
```

The problem is that an imbue will fail if any characters have been read from the file. Some implementations will check to see if there is a BOM marker (putting the chars back if there are none). But checking these BOM characters means the file has been read and thus will make the imbue fail. So always imbue the file before opening.